# How do I solve the "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram, counting, names

I get a type error I cannot solve

This is to construct a counter for a dictionary:

```
counts = dict()
names = ['csev','cwen', 'csev', 'zqian', 'cwen']

#makes new tally for new names and updates existing names
for name in names :
    if name not in counts:
        counts[name] = 1
    else:
        counts[name] = counts[name + 1]

print(counts)
```

Should output:

```
{'csev':2, 'zqian':1, 'cwen':2}
```

Comment: Typo?: `counts[name + 1]` vs `counts[name] + 1`

Comment: Im not following you

Comment: You want to add `1` to `count[name]`, not to `name`, right? That's why I assumed you just made a mistake writing that down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the line10 to

```
counts[name] = counts[name]+1
```

Comment: Thanks so very much !

Answer (score 0):

Even though the only problem you have is `counts[name + 1]` (should be `counts[name] + 1` since you want to increment the count not the name), you should consider using a `collections.Counter` for this task:

```
from collections import Counter
names = ['csev', 'cwen', 'csev', 'zqian', 'cwen']
counts = Counter(names)
```

and while `Counter` is a `dict`-like object, if you want a `dict` object, use:

```
counts = dict(Counter(names))
```

Comment: Much obliged ! Good advice !

Comment: @Neb967 You should mark the answer you see helpful as accepted.